# DocuSign | Embeded Signer not signing envelope

Tags: c#, docusignapi

We are using embedded signers in several different forms.  The issue I am having is some users are not signing their forms or closing the tab before the DocuSign redirect has been completed.  Due to this we'll have forms sitting in an open status until someone notices that a specific form is blank.

What are the recommended best practices to handle cases where an embedded signer does not sign and the form remains open?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best Practice is to use a [webhook (DocuSign connect)](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/webhooks/) to get notified about the status of the envelope.
If the envelope was not signed, but you know that the session is over (that is your UI telling you this) - you can take some action in either the UI or the backend of your app (really depending on your scenario)

Basically, you should have a status component in your integration that is updated in real time and tracks what was signed and what was not signed so that you can use this data to take action.